# ionic, ng-click only works on the second click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

im starting to work with ionic, i tried creating a log-in page, and it works, i can see on the log that when i clicked the function executed and looked for the user, however nothing happens, i have to click 2 or 3 times  so that the view can change i have no idea why this happens. i tried with the submit tag on the form too, and it stays the same.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <ion-view view-title="Iniciar Sesion">
        <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
            <form  name="loginForm" novalidate="">
                <div class="row row-center">
                    <div class="col col-center">
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label">Correo</span>
                            <input type="text" 
                            ng-model="Usuario">
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label">Contraseña</span>
                            <input type="password" ng-model="contrasena" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required >
                        </label> 
                        <button    ng-click="login(Usuario,contrasena)"value="Iniciar" class="button button-block button-calm" ng-disabled="!Usuario || !contrasena">
                            Iniciar
                        </button>
                        {{erronea}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <ion-tabs class="tabs-dark tabs-icon-top">
                <ion-tab title="Olvidé mi contraseña" href="#/olvide" icon="ion-information- circled" ></ion-tab>
                <ion-tab title="Crear Cuenta" href="#/CrearU"  icon="ion-person-add"  ></ion-tab>   
            </ion-tabs>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var datosLogin= function($scope,$location) {
    $scope.login=function (Usuario,contrasena){  
        var ref = new Firebase('https://resplendent-torch-5430.firebaseio.com/');
        ref.authWithPassword({
            email    : Usuario,
            password : contrasena
        }, 
        function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                $scope.erronea="Usuario o contraseña invalida";
            } else {
                $location.path("/inicio");
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Try to put a `console.log( 'click' );` at the beginning of your login function and look in the web console to see what happens. You can also look the Network tab of developer tools to see when the requests start

Comment: If `Firebase` is not Angular aware, you'll need to add `$scope.$apply()` to the callback function. See the last point here ~ https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP should read the fine manual